# How do lodash's isEqual returns true while comparing two objects that have functions in Javascript/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, reference, lodash

I am trying to understand why/how this comparison gets true? As I know, if there is/are function/s in objects it will never be equal because every time parent renders their references change. Why does this equal?

```
// _.isEqual comes from lodash
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
   const myQuestion = _.isEqual(nextProps, this.props) // this is getting true and my question for this line
   return !_.isEqual(nextProps, this.props)
}
```

```
// this is my props
{ 
    "dispatch": function(){},
    "saveHeaderSettings": function(){},
    "buttonFormat": "absolute",
    "externalUpdateEnable": false,
    "isEditModeAllowed": true,
    "isVisiblePivotView": false,
    "isWorkInSubsetEnabled": false,
    "mode": 0,
    "rowUpdateEnable": false,
    "updateMode": 0,
    "updateModes": {
        "isVisibleCellUpdate": true,
        "isVisibleRowUpdate": true,
        "isVisiblePopupUpdate": true
    }
}
```

PS: `dispatch and saveHeaderSettings` methods are coming from Redux's mapDispatchToProps

Comment: "*As I know, if there is/are function/s in objects it will never be equal because every time parent renders their references change.*" From the docs: "*Functions and DOM nodes are compared by strict equality, i.e. `===`.*" so one of these two is wrong. I'd go with the Lodash documentation being correct unless proven otherwise. Try `nextProps.dispatch === this.props.dispatch`

Comment: BUT, the below comparison gets false. What's the difference with the above? I need to understand this kind of comparison whether meaningful or not. Therefore, I can't try object.value === otherobject.value

`var o1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: function() { return 1; } }; 
var o2 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: function() { return 1; } }; 
_.isEqual(o1, o2) // → false`

Comment: Your `o1` and `o2` have *different* functions `o1.c === o2.c //false`. They would be the same function if you had `function foo() { return 1; }` and then `var o1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: foo }, o2 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: foo };`

Comment: `this.props { "dispatch": function(){}, "saveHeaderSettings": function(){}, ...others } and nextProps { "dispatch": function(){}, "saveHeaderSettings": function(){}, ...others }` Aren't these same with my o1, o2 example? Or do you mean redux sets that functions  to the props like you did for foo fn? (Creating it first and then pass it to the this.props and nextProps)?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ dunno what react/redux would do. Hence why I advised you to check `nextProps.dispatch === this.props.dispatch` - if it returns `true` it means that they do share the same function reference. If it returns `false` then evidently Lodash is working not as it is documented.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I tried is that, I put a normal function to the props (not from redux), its behavior changed and gets false. In parent cmp, I passed
`<child onFoo={() =>{}}  /> not equal`
`<child onFoo={function(){}}  /> not equal`
`<child onFoo={this.onFoo.bind(this)}  /> not equal`

all of them changed the reference, but redux's function props do not. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Pretty sure it's because React will only consider them equal if the reference is the same (they literally point to the same function or object or array) whereas the specific reason why _.isEqual exists is to just check that the values have the same attributes and properties. For instance {} === {} is false because they are two different objects, but _.isEqual({}, {}) is true because they have the same properties.